# Autologin with PHP SDK

Tags: php, cakephp, facebook

If a user is already logged in to Facebook account I am trying to auto login the user to my site.

I did similar to example https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php

My site is in cake PHP.

I get the following error OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user. What to do with it?

Comment: The PHP version of try/catch can be your friend.

Answer (score 0):

You need to log at last one time, in your app using facebook account.
This is needed to grant permission for your site acess facebooks users data